# What is the relationship between ptrace and waitpid?

Tags: c, ptrace, waitpid

I am practicing using `ptrace` but I don’t know much about the relationship between it and `waitpid`.

This is my test program:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = 22092;
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("PTRACE_ATTACH");
        return 1;
    } 
    
    //waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
     
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("PTRACE_DETACH");
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I mark `waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED)`, there will be (no such process) problem, but if `waitpid` is added, it can be executed normally. I want to ask what causes it.

Comment: When you say, "If I mark", do you mean, "If I comment"?

Comment: Where will this "no such process" problem arise? Is it when you try to detach from a process you know has exited? Be specific about where this error happens.

Comment: `waitpid()` reports only about the calling process's children.  It must always report an `ECHILD` error (or perhaps a different error) if called by a process that has never forked any children.  This has nothing to do with the `WUNTRACED` flag.